# Is there any way to display an input html tag in a QTextBrowser PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.9

I am using Python 3.9 and PyQt5 and I am trying to display an input html tag in a QTextBrowser widget. When I try to add an input tag the html page looks blank when I view it in the QTextBrowser. Is there any way that I could add an input tag to the QTextBrowser? This is what my HTML code looks like.

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text"></input>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately QTextBrowser only handles a limited subset of HTML4 elements and among them there is no input.

One possible solution is to use QWebEngineView:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

html = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>The input element</h1>
<label for="fname">First name:</label>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
<label for="lname">Last name:</label>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</body>
</html>
"""


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    view = QWebEngineView()
    view.setHtml(html)
    view.resize(640, 480)
    view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```